# VBA- Syntax error in TRANSFORM statement

Tags: vba, excel

I have an error in VBA, this query is operating normally as a cross tab but when I try to switch the VBA, throws me a  Syntax error in TRANSFORM statement  Can someone help me? Thank you.

```
     "TRANSFORM Str(Count([Prijava].[id]))AS O, Str(Count([Prijava].[datumSmrti])) AS U" & _
     "SELECT MKB10.id, IIf([pol].[id]=1,'M','Ž') AS pol, MKB10.NazivLatinski" & _
     "FROM Pol INNER JOIN ((Opstina INNER JOIN Pacijent ON Opstina.id = Pacijent.opstinaID) INNER JOIN (MKB10 INNER JOIN Prijava ON MKB10.id = Prijava.mkb10ID) ON Pacijent.id = Prijava.pacijentID) ON Pol.id = Pacijent.polID" & _
     "GROUP BY MKB10.id, IIf([pol].[id]=1,'M','Ž'), MKB10.NazivLatinski" & _
     "ORDER BY MKB10.id" & _
     "PIVOT starosnoDoba2([starost]) In ('<1','1','2','3','4','5','6','7-9','10-14','15-19','20-29','30-39','40-49','50-59','60-69','70>')"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer is stupid, everything is fine and of course it works but a few things need to be corrected, where there is comma should stand & "" "" & and since it comes after a string to continue with & _ before that should standing space like pollID "
so, looks like this `

```
"TRANSFORM Str(Count([Prijava].[id]))&"" ""& Str(Count([Prijava].[datumSmrti])) " & _
"SELECT MKB10.id &"" ""& IIf([pol].[id]=1,'M','Ž') &"" ""& MKB10.NazivLatinski " & _
"FROM Pol INNER JOIN ((Opstina INNER JOIN Pacijent ON Opstina.id = Pacijent.opstinaID) INNER JOIN (MKB10 INNER JOIN Prijava ON MKB10.id = Prijava.mkb10ID) ON Pacijent.id = Prijava.pacijentID) ON Pol.id = Pacijent.polID " & _
"GROUP BY MKB10.id, IIf([pol].[id]=1,'M','Ž'), MKB10.NazivLatinski " & _
"ORDER BY MKB10.id " & _
"PIVOT starosnoDoba2([starost]) In ('<1','1','2','3','4','5','6','7-9','10-14','15-19','20-29','30-39','40-49','50-59','60-69','70>') "
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 "TRANSFORM Str(Count([Prijava].[id]))AS O, Str(Count([Prijava].[datumSmrti])) AS U " & _
     "SELECT MKB10.id, IIf([pol].[id]=1,'M','Ž') AS pol, MKB10.NazivLatinski " & _
     "FROM Pol INNER JOIN ((Opstina INNER JOIN Pacijent ON Opstina.id = Pacijent.opstinaID) INNER JOIN (MKB10 INNER JOIN Prijava ON MKB10.id = Prijava.mkb10ID) ON Pacijent.id = Prijava.pacijentID) ON Pol.id = Pacijent.polID " & _
     "GROUP BY MKB10.id, IIf([pol].[id]=1,'M','Ž'), MKB10.NazivLatinski " & _
     "ORDER BY MKB10.id " & _
     "PIVOT starosnoDoba2([starost]) In ('<1','1','2','3','4','5','6','7-9','10-14','15-19','20-29','30-39','40-49','50-59','60-69','70>') "
```

You need spaces when joining strings otherwise your text runs together...  Yours was reading `"TRANSFORM..... AS USELECT..."`